# How to integrate $\int |x-t|dx$

Tags: integration

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: How to integrate
$$\int |x-t|dx$$

Comment: You need to split it for $x-t > 0$ and $x - t < 0$. Then integrate each.

Comment: The following simple formula is also useful: $$ \int |x|^{n} \, dx = \frac{x|x|^{n}}{n+1} + C. $$

Answer (score 2):

I would say that  $\int |x-t|dx=(\frac{x^2}{2}-tx)\cdot sign(x-t)+C$